# How to write multiple explicit inner_joins with Diesel?

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I am currently working on an api using actix_web and diesel in rust. Now to my question; I am trying to make an sql request like this one:

```sql
SELECT * FROM customers c
JOIN users u ON u.name = c.customer_no
JOIN address a ON c.fk_address = a.id
WHERE a.name='10715';
```

There is an actual documentation for multiple joins using diesel but just for implicit joins, which can be found here:

https://docs.diesel.rs/diesel/query_dsl/trait.QueryDsl.html#method.inner_join

Whats the difference between explicit and implicit?

Implicit defines the relationsship via a macro:

```rust
users.inner_join(posts)
```

Explicit defines the relationsship in the query statement:

```rust
users.inner_join(posts::table.on(posts::id.eq(user::id)))
```

Does anyone know how to make a request using multiple explicit joins:

this works:

```rust
users.inner_join(posts.inner_join(comments))
```

this doesn't:

```rust
users.inner_join(
    posts::table.on(posts::id.eq(user::id))
        .inner_join(comments::table.on(comments::id.eq(post::id)))
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your initial SQL query would be written with Diesel like this ([complete example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=09d646da0e6e596124bb47ad5c33d469)):

```
customers::table
    .inner_join(users::table.on(users::name.eq(customers::customer_no)))
    .inner_join(address::table.on(address::id.eq(customers::fk_address)))
    .filter(users::name.eq("10715"));
```

You may be wary of this because the [documentation on `.inner_join()`](https://docs.rs/diesel/1.4.8/diesel/query_dsl/trait.QueryDsl.html#method.inner_join) warns against chained vs nested JOINs being different:

> Diesel expects multi-table joins to be semantically grouped based on the relationships. For example, `users.inner_join(posts.inner_join(comments))` is not the same as `users.inner_join(posts).inner_join(comments)`. The first would deserialize into `(User, (Post, Comment))` and generate the following SQL:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM users
>     INNER JOIN posts ON posts.user_id = users.id
>     INNER JOIN comments ON comments.post_id = posts.id
> ```
>
> While the second query would deserialize into `(User, Post, Comment)` and generate the following SQL:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM users
>     INNER JOIN posts ON posts.user_id = users.id
>     INNER JOIN comments ON comments.user_id = users.id
> ```

However, the issue being presented is only a problem because of the implicit ON clause generated by the [`joinable!`](https://docs.rs/diesel/1.4.8/diesel/macro.joinable.html) macro. The query will default to joining `comments` to `users` if they are chained instead of joining `comments` to `posts` as one might expect. That is not a problem when you explicitly provide the ON clause; there is no ambiguity to what you want since you are writing the JOIN criteria yourself.

You can always use [`debug_query`](https://docs.rs/diesel/1.4.8/diesel/fn.debug_query.html) to print out the generated SQL if you have any doubt.

Comment: Thank your for the response :). I do understand the difference, the issue im having, i. e. i cant figure a way out to do nested JOINs like this:
users.inner_join(
    posts::table.on(posts::id.eq(user::id))
        .inner_join(comments::table.on(comments::id.eq(post::id)))
)... this nested explicit join results in an error

Comment: @ilepix I think that should work if you don't nest them and instead chain them like in my first snippet.